# how to make dictionary/list for x,y coordinate as a key and number/character as value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, coordinates

I have such data structure which is shown below:

```
data = [[(24, 21), (24, 59), (24, 97), (24, 134), (23, 172)],
        [(419, 19), (419, 57), (419, 95), (419, 133), (419, 170), (419, 208), (419, 245)], 
        [(469, 20), (469, 57), (469, 94), (468, 132), (469, 170)]]
```

I need such structure:

```
data = [{(24, 21):'1', (24, 59):'2', (24, 97):'3', (24, 134):'4', (23, 172):'0'}, 
        {(419, 19):'1', (419, 57):'2', (419, 95):'3', (419, 133):'4', (419, 170):'0', (419, 208):'x1', (419, 245):'x2'}, 
        {(469, 20):'1', (469, 57):'2', (469, 94):'3', (468, 132):'4', (469, 170):'0'}]
```

Is there any piece of code which can help me sort out this structure or dynamically generate it? Which one is better **list inside dictionary** or **dictionary inside dictionary** for searching key to retrieve value?

Comment: of-course that in matters of searching for a value, a dictionary is better.
while searching in a list take O(N), a key lookup in a dictionary is O(1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
valseq = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '0', 'x1', 'x2']

newdata = [dict(zip(seq, valseq)) for seq in data]
```

Comment: i got my answer but i want to preserve the data the way they are kept.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using a dictionary.